# Get the position of a sphere created in scn file

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, scnscene, arscnview

I created an scn file using Xcode (as you can see below), where there are two nodes (a sphere and a platform). I set up the position of the sphere:

[image: SCN editor window showing a sphere] 
[image: Readout of the sphere position 0.074 0.391 0.392]

I used a class which creates a node platform, which you can resize and move:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDW61.jpg)

After pressing a button it places my scn file instead of that platform (with the same scale, position, and orientation) The problem is I don't know how to get sphere's position from the scene view.

```
  let sphere = SCNNode()
  self.scene.parent!.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in
        if node.name == "sphere" {
            sphere = node
            sphere.position = node.position
            print(sphere.position)
        }
    }
```

Using that code it always prints the position that I set up in the scn file (as you can see above), but I want the real position of it in the view.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDlX6.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sphere.position` you will get the position of `sphere` relative to its parent node. If you want the position in the scene you have to use `sphere.worldPosition`.